# Поиск в бд по сортированной дате

Tags: sql, postgresql

Интересует такой вопрос, имеется таблица с миллиардами записей за 100 лет, где есть поле date(дата создания записи). Нужно выгрузить данные за прошлую неделю с параметром `limit 1`. На прошлой неделе данных не было и запрос начинает перебирать все даты пока не доберется до 1921 года и только потом выведет сообщение, что данных не найдено. Это займет неимоверно много времени. Данные добавляются последовательно и поэтому можно было бы остановить запрос сразу же, как только перепрыгнули необходимую нам дату. Может такой механизм в sql существует? такое условие как:

```
where date between '2021-12-01 00:00:00' and '2021-12-07 23:59:59'
```

будет перебирать всю бд, пока не пройдет все строки. А хотелось бы выполнить такой запрос быстро =)

Comment: Надо создать индекс на поле с датой

Comment: @Mike просто создать или с дополнительными параметрами?

Comment: параметры не нужны.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую! Не подскажите, пожалуйста, какие у этого побочные эффекты есть?

Comment: Индекс занимает место на диске и при вставке или изменении даты запись происходит чуть медленнее,  так как требуется обновлять индекс

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Хотя я бы подумал о партиционировании. Особенно если задача выборки/анализа за весь период редка, а за достаточно узкий промежуток времени - обычное дело.

Comment: @Akina, а как в таком случае запрос будет выглядеть?

Comment: Запрос - точно так же, как и в случае непартиционированной таблицы. См. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/ddl-partitioning.html Сервер достаточно умён, чтобы без дополнительной помощи не лезть в партиции, которые не соответствуют условиям отбора (partition pruning).

Comment: @Akina Спасибо!